# Make UICollectionView always stop scrolling with item centered

Tags: ios, scroll, uicollectionview, centering

I want, basically, something that works like the task switching UI, where no matter how you scroll, an item always ends up perfectly centered.  This is different than paging, I think, since more than one item will be visible (the centered item, and the item to the left and right, if they exist).

How could I achieve this (iOS 7+).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to use `-(void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset` in the `UIScrollViewDelegate` and basically divide by the item with (including line spacing, etc) and provide the proper center for the target.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to essentially "scroll jack" the scroll view by implementing the scroll view delegate methods didBeginDragging, scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating:

In scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating: you could call setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset animated:(BOOL)animated  and calculate the content offset of whatever UICollectionViewCell is in the center.

This should recreate the task switcher UI where if you scroll quickly, you can go through many apps, but it still comes to rest with one app in the center.

Comment: Reasonable, but I can't make it feel quite right.  There is a definite change in the deceleration curve that isn't present in the task switcher UI.

Comment: maybe you could override didScroll and decrease the uiscrollview decelerationrate based on some value

Comment: No, I think [UIScrollViewDelegate scrollViewWillEndDragging:velocity:targetContentOffset](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:) is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, the following Gist code may be helpful: showing an UICollectionView which stopped the scrolling item on the center of the screen.

```
/*
     *
        |<-------     view width     -------->|
        ---------------------------------------
        |                                     |
        |<-w0->|<ws>|<--   wi  -->|<ws>|<-w0->|
 ---------------    ---------------    ---------------
 |             |    |             |    |             |
 |             |    |             |    |             |
 ---------------    ---------------    ---------------
        |                                     |
        |                                     |
        ---------------------------------------
     * 
     * w0: itemEdgeOffset
     * ws: space
     * wi: itemWidth
     * in this example: ws == w0
     */
```

[Gist link](https://gist.github.com/ylem/9158e1e3ad14958202adc6db7f6ec448)